# Plotly.js: Issue graphing two-type chart from CSV files

Tags: javascript, plotly, plotly.js

I've taken [this Plotly Chart Studio](https://plotly.com/%7Echerryleh/2/) .js code and have been trying to replace the x and y values so they are taken from CSV files.

```
var url1 ='https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cherryleh/testcsvs/main/RS01_ETaverage.csv';



var url2 = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cherryleh/testcsvs/main/RS01_ETmonthlyavg.csv';



        function makeplot() {
          Plotly.d3.csv(url1, function(data){ processData(data) } );
          Plotly.d3.csv(url2, function(data){ processData(data) } );
        };


        var x1 = [], y1 = [], x2 = [], y2 = [];

        function processData(allRows) {

            for (var i=0; i<allRows.length; i++) {
                row = allRows[i];
                if (row['Month1'] !== undefined) {
                    x1.push(row['Month1']);}
                if (row['ET1'] !== undefined) {
                    y1.push(row['ET1']);}
                if (row['Month2'] !== undefined) {
                    x2.push(row['Month2']);}
                if (row['ET2'] !== undefined) {
                    y2.push(row['ET2']);}
            }

            

            trace1.x = x1;
            trace1.y = y1;
            trace2.x = x2;
            trace2.y = y2;

            console.log(trace1.y);

            
        }
```

Whole code: https://jsfiddle.net/t2q8fzxn/

When I console log the x and y values they work fine, but the graph remains empty. Any thoughts to why?

Answer (score 0):

In your [code](https://jsfiddle.net/t2q8fzxn/), when you call your function `makeplot` which in turn calls the function `processData`, even though you modify the `x` and `y` properties of your objects `trace1` and `trace2` inside the processData function, these changes are only local to the processData function.

Once you are outside of the processData function, your `trace1` and `trace2` objects no longer have the `x` and `y` properties. And since your plotting code is outside of the scope of your processData function, your trace objects no longer have the properties `x` and `y` which is why your plots are blank.

If you want to see this for yourself, try running the following code after you run makeplot() and you'll see that the properties of the traces aren't changed:

```
makeplot();
console.log("here are the traces after makeplot has been run")
console.log(trace1) 
console.log(trace2)
// the traces won't have the properties x or y
```

To get your plot to display correctly, what I did is make your processData function call another function called `makePlotly` which takes `trace` as an argument (similar to [this example](https://plotly.com/javascript/ajax-call/#plotting-csv-data-from-ajax-call) from the documentation). The structure of the function calls looks like this:

```
function processData(allRows) {

    // process your csvs
    // set properties for trace1 or trace2 depending on url1 or url2
    // call a separate plotting function to plot each trace individually
    
    var trace1 = {...}
    var trace2 = {...}

    if (condition) {
        makePlotly(trace1)
    }
    else {
        makePlotly(trace2)
    }

function makePlotly(trace) {
    var data = [trace];
    var layout = {...}
    Plotly.plot('plotly-div', data, layout);
}
```

To avoid any issues about the scope of `trace1` and `trace2`, I defined them inside the `processData` function (it seems unnecessary to define the traces outside of the function since they won't be reused anyway). You can find my fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/merillium/2hyvzLja/108/), which produces the following plot.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. Adding the makePlotly function makes a lot more sense. You'll see on my Plotly chart studio link that I'm trying to use one trace for the line and one trace for the bars. What's causing the duplication?

Comment: i just realized the problem is that for each url we read in, we are calling `processData` and `makePlotly`. in other words, after we read in the data from url1 and use it to fill trace1, we pass both trace1 and the empty trace2 to the plotting function, and then after we read in the data from url, we use it to fill trace2 and pass both the filled trace 1 and trace2 to the plotting function. this means we get one empty trace, two copies of the bar, and one line chart. let me see if I can fix this.

Comment: @cheu I don't know if you figured out a solution already, but I added some more conditions to check whether trace1 and trace2 already have had data read into them. it's hacky, but it seems to work without plotting empty or duplicate traces